# MySql connection refused when debug on docker machine

Tags: c#, mysql, docker, asp.net-core, ssh.net

Then I run debug on IIS Express all is going OK.

I make connection to DB over ssh by Ssh.NET library.

```
PasswordConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo("here is remote ip", 22, "ssh login here", "password for ssh")
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
};
var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
client.Connect();
ForwardedPortLocal portForward = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 22, "127.0.0.1", 3306);
client.AddForwardedPort(portForward);
portForward.Start();

services.AddDbContext<WhetherContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=22;Database=MyDb;Uid=MySqlDatabaseLogin;Pwd=DbPassword;SslMode=none;")));
```

When I run it on docker-machine, it throws exception when try to use context.

[image]

[image]

I use Linux containers. What may cause that?

UPD: 
**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x
RUN bash -
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY WhetherService/WhetherService.csproj WhetherService/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WhetherService
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app


FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WhetherService.dll"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  whetherservice:
    image: alexandrs/whetherservice
    build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: WhetherService/Dockerfile
```

**docker-compose.ci.build.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  ci-build:
    image: microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0-2.0
    volumes:
       - .:/src
    working_dir: /src
    command: /bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./WhetherService.sln && dotnet publish ./WhetherService.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish"
```

**/etc/mysql/my.cnf file**:

> The MySQL database server configuration file.
>
> You can copy this to one of:
>    - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
>    - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
>
> One can use all long options that the program supports.  Run program
>   with --help to get a list of available options and with 
>   --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
>
> For explanations see 
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html
>
> - IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this
>     file!    The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
>
> !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
>
> !includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

**netstat -tln :**

[image]

Comment: have you checked to which ip address is binded mysql? 127.0.0.1 or docker instance ip

Comment: This may be a permission issue, have you granted access to the IP address of the docker container?

Comment: How are you running docker? Show the `Dockerfile` and if applicable command or docker compose file

Comment: @MikeTung added

Comment: Is the mysql db your local one or a docker image?

Comment: @MikeTung remote running mysql server on Ubuntu.

Comment: @AlexandrS you find any solution. I am facing problem when connecting with mysql 8.0, .net core 3.1 application with caching_sha2_password

Comment: @KamranShahid I didn't find any solution. After some attempts, I on PostgreSQL... And haven't tried again MySQL

Comment: Thanks @AlexandrS for update

Answer (score 0):

From the info you have given, it seems you are just forgetting to connect your remote mysql to your image. The way to do that is to open a port on the remote server to listen on, then in the docker image where you run that program you'll need to connect using a conn string with the hostname or ip address of that remote server.